# App:clean delete directory in android studio error

Tags: android

Sometimes the error occur as the title.
There are not error in syntax and others.
I use windows OS and Android Studio version 2.2.3.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
>   Unable to delete directory: C:\Users\sang\Desktop\android_studio_mob_term\mobile_programming_17-master\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support

Can I delete the directory?

Comment: post the code where error is occurring and the complete error log please!

Comment: remove the directory manually inside app (build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support) folder

Answer (score 0):

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

add this in project level gradle at bottom

Answer (score 0):

go to build.gradle project level and comment this script

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

then clean your project.

again uncomment the script

build your project and it's done.